# Get a href from specific table cell

Tags: jquery

Dear experts I have following Table Structure

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">short description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="Disclose.html">View</a></td>
<td><a class="AgendaNote" href="#">Take Note</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want on click class AgendaNote I need extract the href attribute of first td that is "Disclose.html"

I tried

```
alert($(this).parent().siblings(":first > a").attr("href"));
```

but it showing undefined.

Please help me.

Comment: Is it always just the previoud TD anchor child? Or your HTML markup can vary?

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev().children().attr("href");` this worked

Comment: Of course it works here, but won't if you modify in some way HTML markup. So that was my question. Anyway, glad you have fixed your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`siblings` method doesn't work that way, the target `a` element is not the sibling of the parent `td` element so the query fails and `attr` returns an `undefined` value, you should at first select the sibling `td` element and then select the child element.

```
$(this).parent().siblings(":first").children('a').attr("href");
```

But better option here is using the `prev` method:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children().attr("href");
```

Comment: Sorry, misread HTML markup, was thinking `<td colspan="2">short description</td>` to be in same row

Comment: the OP asked `I need extract the href attribute of FIRST td that is "Disclose.html"` so not the previous `td`. Would that mean that you need to go back to `tr` level, then select the first `td`?

Comment: @wf4 but here the first is the same as the previous, what is the problem then? I asked OP if HTML can vary, he still didn't answer that simple question. If ya, then i'm quite agree with your comment

Comment: it may not be a problem and would work ok in this example, but that is not how the question was asked. You even asked for clarification on this exact point above. @A.Wolff

Answer (score 2):

The target `a` is in the previous sibling of the current td so try

```
alert($(this).parent().prev().find('a').attr("href"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/28msZ/)

Comment: Thanks for your help I wish i could accept your answer too :(